# EncryptDecrypt XOR

Tags: java, loops, encryption

I'm having trouble understanding the entirety of this encryption scheme implemented in my DIS(Distributed systems) course, and want to test my theory of how it executes, any response is appreciated.

-

The for-loop will loop through the rawString, where it after every character in the rawString will append (add to it?) the binary value of the modulus of theEncryption key. Where the modulus of the encryption key would be 9/8 which would be 1 for the first char in the rawstring, or am I completely off target?

Could anyone elaborate on what exactly happens?

Also i know it's a bad encryption but it functions more as a proof of concept than any real function

[image: XOR encrotion]

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which part is confusing you?

Comment: Additionally - the code you posted is actually broken - using `StringBuilder` is forcing a conversion from binary to ASCII or UTF8 (unsure which) - this will cause data loss.

Comment: Convert both strings to ASCII and XOR that, HTTP is perfectly fine transporting binary after all. By the way, I don't know what "DIS" means in this context. I presume that "restulf" means "restful" though.

Comment: Please note - in Java the String (and StringBuilder) are intended for **printable** characters. Just applying XOR the resulting value may not be printable and may (will) be corrupted. When using XOR you may work on byte array and encode the byte array as hex/base64 to get printable values again